# How do you parse recursive JSON in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

I am receiving JSON from a server where the data is recursive. What is the best way to parse this into a convenient Swift data structure?

Defining a Swift Codable data structure to parse it into fails because the recursive properties are not allowed.

The Swift compiler reports: "Value type 'FamilyTree.Person' cannot have a stored property that recursively contains it"

```
{
   "familyTree": {
      "rootPerson": {
        "name": "Tom",
        "parents": {
           "mother": {
              "name": "Ma",
              "parents": {           
                 "mother": {
                    "name": "GraMa",
                    "parents": {}
                  },
                 "father": {
                    "name": "GraPa",
                    "parents": {}
                 }
               }
            },
           "father": {
              "name": "Pa",
              "parents": {}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Ideally the end result would be a bunch of person objects pointing to their mother and father objects starting from a rootPerson object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible implementation using classes.
(Swift 5 synthesizes default initializers for classes. Dont remember if so for Swift 4)

```
import Foundation

var json: String = """
{
   "familyTree": {
      "rootPerson": {
        "name": "Tom",
        "parents": {
           "mother": {
              "name": "Ma",
              "parents": {
                 "mother": {
                    "name": "GraMa",
                    "parents": {}
                  },
                 "father": {
                    "name": "GraPa",
                    "parents": {}
                 }
               }
            },
           "father": {
              "name": "Pa",
              "parents": {}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
"""




final class Parents: Codable{
    let mother: Person?
    let father: Person?

}

final class  Person: Codable{
    let name: String
    let parents: Parents?
}


final class RootPerson: Codable {
    var rootPerson: Person
}

final class Root: Codable {
    var familyTree: RootPerson
}

var jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)!


do{
   let familyTree = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: jsonData)
    print("Ma •••>", familyTree.familyTree.rootPerson.parents?.mother?.name)
    print("GraPa •••>", familyTree.familyTree.rootPerson.parents?.mother?.parents?.father?.name)
    print("Shoud be empty •••>", familyTree.familyTree.rootPerson.parents?.mother?.parents?.father?.parents?.father?.name)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first thought is to create structs such as:

```
struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
    var parents: Parents
}

struct Parents: Codable {
    var mother: Person?
    var father: Person?
}
```

But this doesn't work since you can't have recursive stored properties like this.

Here is one possible working solution:

```
let json = """
{
   "familyTree": {
      "rootPerson": {
        "name": "Tom",
        "parents": {
           "mother": {
              "name": "Ma",
              "parents": {
                 "mother": {
                    "name": "GraMa",
                    "parents": {}
                  },
                 "father": {
                    "name": "GraPa",
                    "parents": {}
                 }
               }
            },
           "father": {
              "name": "Pa",
              "parents": {}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
"""

struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
    var parents: [String: Person]
}

struct FamilyTree: Codable {
    var rootPerson: Person
}

struct Root: Codable {
    var familyTree: FamilyTree
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let tree = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(tree)
```

In a playground this will correctly parse the JSON.

The `parents` dictionary of `Person` will have keys such as `"mother"` and `"father"`. This supports a person have any number of parents with any role.