# Is there a way to reuse model within itself?

Tags: swift

I have an app that stores User (UserModel) Friend list. if a friend clicks one user, its type is the same type (UserModel). In Swift it wouldnt allow using the model recursively, giving me this error:

"Value type 'OwnerModel' cannot have a stored property that recursively contains it"

```
import Foundation
struct OwnerModel: Codable {
    var ownerId: Int
    var ownerEmail: String
    var ownerUserName: String
    var ownerCommonName: String
    var ownerBirthDate: String
    var ownerCountry: String
    var ownerBdayReminderId: Int
    var ownerIsVerified: Bool
    var ownerIsOnline: Bool
    var ownerIsEventGreeted: Bool
    var ownerIsBirthdayGreeted: Bool
    var ownerAllowGreeting: Bool
    var ownerFriends: OwnerModel
}
```

Is there a way I can reuse the OwnerModel under ownerFriends?

Comment: This is a problem with `Codable`, see this very recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342919/how-do-you-parse-recursive-json-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

This can't work because structs are value types. So each OwnerModel would have to have a OwnerModel inside it, which would have to have an OwnerModel inside it, which would have to have an OwnerModel inside it.... This can never resolve. Since you've marked this Codable, try to write the JSON you expect to encode this to.

That said, `ownerFriends` seems plural, which would suggest `[OwnerModel]`, and that's not a problem, since you could have zero of them:

```
struct OwnerModel: Codable {
    ...
    var ownerFriends: [OwnerModel]
}
```

Remember again, however, that structs are value types. So each OwnerModel is just a value. It's not a reference to any other object. If you want to refer to other owners, you may want to store IDs rather than the actual object (or use classes in order to create references).